# Should I relate all of my MySQL tables to each other?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm working on a personal project for timekeeping on various projects, but I'm not sure of the best way to structure my database.

A simplified breakdown of the structure is as follows:

- Each client can have multiple reports.
- Each report can have multiple line items.
- Each line item can have multiple time records.

There will ultimately be more relationships, but that's the basis of the application. As you can see, each item is related to the item beneath it in a one-to-many relationship.

My question is, should I relate each table to each "parent" table above it? Something like this:

```
clients
    id

reports
    id
    client_id

line_items
    id
    report_id
    client_id

time_records
    id
    report_id
    line_item_id
    client_id
```

And as it cascaded down, there would be more and more foreign keys added to each new table.

My initial reaction is that this is not the correct way to do it, but I would love to get some second(and third!) opinions.

Comment: How are you (conceptually) differentiating between line items and time records? Is a line item a task of sorts?

Comment: Yes, a line item would be a task. For example, a line item might read, "Built timekeeping application," and it would have multiple time records(30 minutes here, 12 minutes there, etc) that would add up to the total amount of time spent on a line item.

Comment: Given that, I think your current design is perfectly acceptable (minus the extra IDs in the child tables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of the way you're doing it is that you could check all time records for, say, a specific client id without needing a join.  But really, it isn't necessary.  All you need is to store a reference back up one "level" so to speak.  Here are some examples from the "client" perspective:

**To get a specific client's reports:** (simple; same as current schema you suggest)

```
SELECT * FROM `reports`
    WHERE `client_id` = ?;
```

**To get a specific client's line items:** (new schema; don't need "client_id" in table)

```
SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items`
    JOIN `reports` ON `reports`.`id` = `line_items`.`id`
    JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`id` = `reports`.`client_id`
    WHERE `clients`.`id` = ?;
```

**To get a specific client's time entries:** (new schema; don't need "client_id" or "report_id" in table)

```
SELECT `time_records`.* FROM `time_records`
    JOIN `line_items` ON `line_items`.`id` = `time_records`.`line_item_id`
    JOIN `reports` ON `reports`.`id` = `line_items`.`id`
    JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`id` = `reports`.`client_id`
    WHERE `client_id` = ?;
```

**So, the revised schema would be:**

```
clients
    id

reports
    id
    client_id

line_items
    id
    report_id

time_records
    id
    line_item_id
```

**EDIT:**

Additionally, I would consider using views to simplify the queries (I assume you'll use them often), definitely creating indexes on the join columns, and utilizing foreign key references for normalization (InnoDB only).

Comment: I wish I could accept all the answers, but I felt yours most thoroughly explained it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, if there is no direct relation in the elements of the model, then there should not be direct relation in the corresponding tables. Otherwise your data will have redundancies and you will have problems for updating.

This is the right way:

```
clients
    id

reports
    id
    client_id

line_items
    id
    report_id

time_records
    id
    line_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create `client_id` on `line_items` table if you never join line items directly clients, becouse you can get that by `reports` table. Same happens to others FKs.

I recommend you think in your report needs/queries over this collection of data before create redundant foreign keys who can complicate your development.

Create redundant FKs is not difficult if you need them in the future, some ALTERS and UPDATE SELECTS solves your problem.

If you not have so much information in the `line_items`, you can denormalize and add this info in the `time_records`.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere there is a direct relationship between two tables, you should use foreign keys to keep the data integrity.  Personally, I would look at a structure like this:

```
Client
    ClientId

Report
    ReportId
    ClientId

LineItem
    LineItemId
    ReportId

TimeRecord
    TimeRecordId
    LineItemId
```

In this example, you do not need `ClientId` in `LineItem` because you have that relationship through the `Report` table. The major disadvantage of having `ClientId` in all of your tables is that if the business logic does not enforce consistency of these values (a bug is in the code) you can run into situations where you get different values if you search based on

```
Report:
   ReportId = 3
   ClientId = 2
LineItem:
   LineItemId = 1
   ReportId = 3
   ClientId = 3
```

In the above situation, you would be looking at `ClientId = 2` if your query went through `Report` and `ClientId = 3` if your query went through `LineItem`  It is difficult once this happens to determine which relationship is correct, and where the bug is.

Also, I would advocate for not having `id` columns, but instead more explicit names to describe what the `id` is used for. (`ReportId` or `ClientId`)  In my opinion, this makes Joins easier to read.  As an example:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumberOfLineItems
FROM Client AS c
INNER JOIN Report AS r ON c.ClientId = r.ClientId
INNER JOIN LineItem AS li ON r.ReportId = li.ReportId
WHERE c.ClientId = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

As personal opinion, I would have:

```
clients
    id

time_records
    id
    client_id
    report
    line_item
    report_id
```

That way all of your fields are over in the `time_records` table. You can then do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'time_records'
WHERE 'time_records'.'client_id' = 16542
   AND 'time_records'.'report' = 164652
ORDER BY 'time_records'.'id' ASC
```

Comment: While formatting your query, I also changed `==` to `=`.  I hope this change was what you intended; sorry if it was not.

Comment: Thanks! It is. Trying faster than I was thinking it would appear.